# Cassandra - TimedOutException - Wrong prompt? - strange acknowledged_by and acknowledged_by_batchlog value set-up

Tags: cassandra

I'm trying to get a bit more information about my TimedOutException.

After inputing data for 6 minutes(a lot of insert succeed), i get:

Caused by: TimedOutException(acknowledged_by:**0**, acknowledged_by_batchlog:**true**)

The Exception occurs during batched insert operations. I'm using cassandra 1.2.6. I can't perceive any special cassandra behavior during this timeOutException occur.

I red about the acknowledged_by and the acknowledged_by_batchlog and cannot understand the set-up of this value in my case(0,true)(Wrong prompt?). It is the case of atomic_batch_mutate, so why this 2 value reveal other facts?

JavaDoc in cassandra code, placed over the **ACKNOWLEDGED** attribute:
"if a write operation was acknowledged by some replicas but not by enough to
satisfy the required ConsistencyLevel, the number of successful
replies will be given here. In case of atomic_batch_mutate method this field
will be set to -1 if the batch was written to the batchlog and to **0 if it wasn't**."

JavaDoc in cassandra code, placed over the **ACKNOWLEDGED_BY_BATCHLOG** attribute:
"**in case of atomic_batch_mutate method this field tells if the batch was written to the batchlog.**"

It's a Wrong prompt?(bug?) Or? Maybe someone know something about this kind of set-up...

Comment: I dont get the Exception anymore after setting the replicationfactor of the keyspace (from former 1) to 2 or 3. I can reproduce the Problem!(Now running on cassandra 1.2.9)